# Input "x" instead of "#1"

Tags: macros, latex3, xparse, l3fp

Is there a possibility to have `x` instead of `#1` for the name of the variable in the macro?

I tried it with `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, but that did not work.

Many thanks for your help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\FuncValue}{ O{} m m }
 {% #1 = option list, #2 = value, #3 = function
  \group_begin:
    \ensuremath{f(x)=x^2; \qquad 
    f\left(#2\right) = \thomas_function_value:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomas_function_value:nn
 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_thomas_funk_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { x } { \c{\#}1 } \l_thomas_funk_tl
    \cs_set:Nn \__thomas_functionValue_function:n  { #2 }
        \fp_eval:n
         {
          round( \__thomas_functionValue_function:n { \fp_eval:n { #1 } }, 3 )
         }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\FuncValue{2^3}{#1^2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\regex_replace_all:nnN { x } { (#1) } \l_thomas_funk_tl`?

Comment: @Manuel, Thank you. This works in the expected way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I do not really understand your steps in between, I guess the following code will do what you want (if you want to just calculate the function's value at a given point you call `x`).

[image: functions]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\FuncValue}{ O{} m m }
 {% #1 = option list, #2 = value, #3 = function
  \group_begin:
    \ensuremath{f(x)=#3; \qquad 
    f\left(#2\right) = \thomas_function_value:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomas_function_value:nn
 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_thomas_funk_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { x } { ( #1 ) } \l_thomas_funk_tl
    \fp_eval:n
       {
         round( \l_thomas_funk_tl , 3 )
       }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\FuncValue{2^3}{x^2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: -TeXnician, yes this is what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution along your lines, although there are simpler ways. The problem is in doing the correct substitution: `\#` does not stand for the parameter marker, whereas `\cP\#` does. Next, you have to set the replacement text for `\__thomas_functionValue_function:n` to be the *value* of the modified token list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\FuncValue}{ O{} m m }
 {% #1 = option list, #2 = value, #3 = function
  \ensuremath % <-- is it really needed?
   {
    f(x)=#3;
    \qquad 
    f(#2) = \thomas_function_value:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomas_function_value:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_thomas_funk_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { x } { \cP\#1 } \l_thomas_funk_tl
  \cs_set:NV \__thomas_functionValue_function:n  \l_thomas_funk_tl
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    round( \__thomas_functionValue_function:n { \fp_eval:n { #1 } }, 3 )
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\FuncValue{2^3}{x^2}

\FuncValue{pi}{sin(x)+cos(x)}

\FuncValue{pi/2}{sin(x)+cos(x)}

\end{document}
```

The typesetting of the functions is horrible, of course; I believe that your options will take care for it.

[image]

Comment: -@egreg, I am excited about your solution.